# Allow ufw rule to curl localhost for a specific port

Tags: ufw

I want to allow `curl -if localhost:54321` only with `ufw`. What rule can I apply from the command line?

I have tried `ufw allow proto tcp from any to any port 54321` and `ufw status` shows the following:

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
54321/tcp                  ALLOW       Anywhere
54321/tcp (v6)             ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

But still I'm unable to `curl -if localhost:54321`.

Comment: There's a pretty clear example on the ufw man page that allows tcp connections from an IP to a port. Did you try that one?

Answer (score 2):

Got it:

```
ufw allow proto tcp from any to any port 54321,54322
ufw allow out proto tcp from any to any port 54321,54322
```

Answer (score 1):

From `man ufw`:

> ```
> Allow access to udp 1.2.3.4 port 5469 from 1.2.3.5 port 5469:
>
>     ufw allow proto udp from 1.2.3.5 port 5469 to 1.2.3.4 port 5469
> ```

Hence the command you're looking for is

```
     ufw allow proto tcp from <ip_source> to <ip_destination> port 54321
```